# Mongodb aggregation performance issue in sharded env

Tags: performance, mongodb, sharding

I have legacy code that pulls analytics data from mongo (over 10 millions documents) and builds reports. It works really slow because current code heavily uses aggregation ($unwind, $sum, $group, etc.)

Here is how docs in old collection looks like:

```
{
  serverId: 'srv1',
  dateVisited: '2014-12-24',
  campaignId: 'c1',
  ...
  landingpageClicks: [
    {...},
    {...}
  ],
  offerTrackings: [
    {
      amount: 10
    },
    {
      amount: 22
    }
    {
      amount: 18
    }
  ]
}
```

To get statistics from such collection, the previous programmer used  $match, $unwind, $group and $sum. I mapreduced this collection to new one and now it looks like this:

```
{
  _id: {
      serverId: 'srv1',
      dateVisited: '2014-12-24',
      campaignId: 'c1'
  },
  value: {
    landingpageClicksCount: 2,
    offerTrackingsCount: 3,
    offerTrackingsAmount: 50
  }
}
```

As result, my new collection became twice smaller, but I still have to use aggregation when I need to pull stats for specific date (for all servers and campaigns). $group doesn't support indexes, so queries are still extremely slow.

I've set up sharding with 3 nodes (locally, both are on the same machine), but now queries are twice slower!
db.printShardingStatus() shows that chunks were distributed between all 3 nodes. But why it became much slower now?

P.S. I'm pretty new to sharding setup, and I'm not sure if my sharding key is good:

```
{
  '_id.serverId': 1,
  '_id.dateVisited': 1,
  '_id.campaignId': 1'
}
```

**[Updated]** Aggregation to collect stats for specific date (withouth groupping by multiple params):

```
db.clicks.aggregate([
  {$match: {'_id.dateVisited': '2014-12-24'}},
  {$group:{
    _id: '$_id.dateVisited',
    totalLandingpageClicksCount: {$sum: '$value.landingpageClicksCount'},
    totalOfferTrackingsCount: {$sum: '$value.offerTrackingsCount'},
    totalOfferTrackingsAmount: {$sum: '$value.offerTrackingsAmount'}
  }}
])
```

Also user can request groupping by multiple fields, e.g. group then date, then by serverId, then by campaignId and report should look like this:

```
2014-12-24    |  50 lp clicks  |  21 offer clicks  | $600 // srv1 + srv2
  srv1        |  20 lp clicks  |  11 offer clicks  | $400 // campaign1 + campaign2
    campaign1 |  10 lp clicks  |   6 offer clicks  | $100
    campaign2 |  10 lp clicks  |   5 offer clicks  | $300
  srv2        |  30 lp clicks  |  10 offer clicks  | $200 // campaign3 + campaign4
    campaign3 |  20 lp clicks  |   4 offer clicks  | $100
    campaign4 |  10 lp clicks  |   6 offer clicks  | $100
```

Comment: Why did you set up sharding? Purely to speed up the aggregation? Can we see the aggregation?

Comment: I updated my post with example of aggregation query and example of desired output. Yes, I need to speed up the aggregation. find() works perfectly with indexes, but aggregation is still slow

Comment: @wdberkeley, should sharding help to speed up aggregation?

Comment: Do you have an index on `_id.dateVisited`? Also, if it's a date it might be better to store it as a date type. Sharding can improve some parts of aggregation, like a `$match` stage under certain conditions, but it doesn't really help with a `$group` stage. It's not a good reason to shard.

Comment: Yes, I've created index on `_id.dateVisited`. `db.clicks.find({'_id.dateVisited': 'XXX-XX-XX'})` is fast enough, but aggregation is extremely slow. And I have no idea how to speed it up.

Comment: How many docs are there per date visited? Sharding may be slowing you down here. A `$group` stage requires the documents to be sent to the primary shard for grouping. What kind of performance are you expecting? You shouldn't expect real-time speeds with aggregation in general, and definitely with this sort of reporting query. If you want real-time querying of this sort, you'd need to design the schema to support it.

Comment: ~10 000 docs per date visited.Yes,realtime speed is is my goal.Should I create many collections with `_id` containing possible inputs,and `counts` containing counts for these inputs? E.g `{_id: {dateVisited: '2014-11-10'}, counts: {...}}` to get stats only by `dateVisited`, `{_id: {dateVisited: '2014-11-10', serverId: 'srv1'}, counts: {...}}` to get stats by `dateVisited`+`serverId`?That way no aggregation required and find() queries will be fast.But I'd like to avoid such approach because I have many possible input params,so I have to create many collections and update counts for all of them